# jQuery - Reselect Tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery tabs, which are initialized from a static .js file using a selector:
$()

```
.ready(function () {
    $('.jqTabsStandard').tabs();
});
```

I'm using ASP.NET (not that it makes a difference I think), but when I click a button in one of the tabs, is there a way I can re-select that tab when the page reloads. I was thinking of sticking the tab section in an UpdatePanel. I was hoping there's a way I could trigger the tab to reselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be:

[UI/API/1.8/Tabs - jQuery JavaScript Library](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-select)

or:

```
$('.jqTabsStandard').tabs( "disable" ).tabs( "enable" ).tabs( "select" , index );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hiddenField to persist the currently selected tab, then when the refresh happen, check the value of that Hidden field, if you found a value( for example: 1 as the index of the 2nd tab) you can grab this value, and reselect the tab.

for example:

1- after getting the current index of the selected tab:

```
$("#ID_OfYourHiddenField").val(INDEX_VALUE);
```

2- after your postback, get the value from this hidden field

```
var tabIndex = $("#ID_OfYourHiddenField").val();
```

3- select the tab using jQuery tab

```
$('.jqTabsStandard').tabs( "select" , tabIndex );
```